# How do I share functionality and shorten code on event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#a").click(function(evt) {
         $("#bodyR").load("./inc/backa.php")
         evt.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#b").click(function(evt) {
       $("#bodyR").load("./inc/backb.php")
       evt.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#c").click(function(evt) {
       $("#bodyR").load("./inc/backc.php")
       evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I was trying to shorten the script but I couldn't figure it out. I feel like I'm repeating myself here.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Did you try running it through a minifier?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#a,#b,#c").click(function(evt) { // comma selector to target more than one element
     $("#bodyR").load("./inc/back"+this.id+".php") // path built using the element's id
     evt.preventDefault();
  })
})
```